# Difference between 'enable role switch' (from Link Policy Settings ) and 'allow role switch' (in ACL connection) ? Bluetooth BR/EDR/LE

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

What is the difference between 'enable role switch' which is in Link Policy Settings and 'allow role switch' during ACL connection establishment of bluetooth ?